# Unquote strings in list R

Tags: r, string, text, quotes

I have a list of variables in a vector:

```
var_names <- c("varname1", "varname2", "varname3")
```

And I would like to loop through the names in that vector but I need the plain text without the quotes (the function wont accept the argument as a string). Like in the below code:

```
# What I want
result <- some_function(x = "varname1", y = varname1)

result <- some_function(x = var_names[1], y = ??)
```

Where the `var_names[1]` will give me the string, but I also need the non-string(?) unquote plain text as well. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Did you write the `some_function`? If so, you should consider enabling it to yalltake strings. Anyway you can use `as.name("a")`

Comment: I did not write the function, but thanks, ```as.name()``` works.